# (others => '-') in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to set res to "----" which is done in an example in my book. When I run the following code I get the message "failure1":

```
  library IEEE;
  use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
  use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity alu is
    port(a,b: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
    aluc: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
    res: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
    cout: out STD_LOGIC);
end;

architecture synth of alu is
    signal bm: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
    signal temp1, temp2: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);
    begin
    bm <= (not b)+1;
    temp1 <= ("0" & a)+("0" & b);
    temp2 <= ("0" & a)+("0" & bm);
    process(all) begin
        case aluc is
        when "00" => res <= temp1(3 downto 0);
        when "10" => res <= (a and b);
        when "11" => res <="1111";
        when others => res <=(others => '-');
        
        end case;
    end process;
 
    
end;
```

testbench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity tb is
end entity tb;


architecture behavioral of tb is

component alu is 
port(a,b: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
    aluc: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
    res: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
    cout: out STD_LOGIC);
end component;

signal tb_a, tb_b, tb_res: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
signal tb_aluc: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
signal tb_cout: STD_LOGIC;

begin

DUT: alu
port map(
a=>tb_a, b=>tb_b, res=>tb_res,aluc=>tb_aluc,cout=>tb_cout);


process begin
wait for 10 ns;
tb_b<="0000";
tb_a<="0001";
tb_aluc <= "01";
wait for 10 ns;
assert tb_res="----" report "failure1";
wait;
end process;
end;
```

If I change

```
when others => res <=(others => '-');
```

to

```
when others => res <=(others => '1');
```

and

```
assert tb_res="----" report "failure1";
```

to

```
assert tb_res="1111" report "failure1";
```

I do not get the errormessage.

I tried to isolate the problem and the following code does not give an error message:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity testy is

port(a: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0));
end;

architecture synth of testy is
begin
     a <= (others=>'-');
end;
```

testbench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb is
end entity tb;

architecture behavioral of tb is

component testy is 
port(a: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0));
end component;

signal tb_a: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);

begin

DUT: testy
    port map(a=>tb_a);
    
process begin
wait for 10 ns;
assert tb_a="----" report "failure";
wait;
end process;
end;
```

But this did not give an error. So do you see why I get the errormessage in the first code?

Comment: `"assert tb_res="----" report "failure1"` .... Not sure what you are trying to achieve with this statement. You are literally asserting that "If tb result is not don't care, report it as a failure". Is this really what you need?

Comment: @MituRaj Yes, I am trying to find out why it works in one case, but not the other.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. You are comparing tb_res (value = doesn't care) with some number in right side, which is also doesn't care. You can't determine what would be the output of comparing two such values whose values can be anything. The result should hence be don't care as well. It won't be deterministic as you presume.

Comment: @MituRaj Thank you. I see, but why is it that it works in the second case?

Comment: Because tb_res = 1111 is true for the stimulus you gave to DUT. So assertion is true, not a fail.

Comment: @MituRaj I do not mean that case, I mean the case in the second example where tb_a="----".

Comment: Why should you care about the output?  There is no meaning in comparing or asserting a signal to be don't care in a design. We don't know what two values tools would compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a very subtle problem.

The short answer is, for this problem, do not use the package `ieee.numeric_std_unsigned`.

If you look in `ieee.std_logic_1164`, you will find that it does not overload the implicitly defined `=` operator.  Hence, matching will be character based - probably like you are expecting.

When you include `ieee.numeric_std_unsigned`, it treats '0' or 'L' as a '0', '1' or 'H' as a '1', and everything else as an 'X'.   This is fine for RTL design, however, it is not so good for testbenches where you want to match on meta values.   For `ieee.numeric_std.unsigned` it does the exact same thing.

For RTL, if you are really doing math, I recommend that you use `ieee.numeric_std` and types unsigned and signed.

With VHDL-2008, the language also introduces matching relationals, `?=, ?/=, ...`.   For equality, these treat `-` as don't care.   Matching relationals also return std_ulogic values rather than boolean (when used with std_logic/std_ulogic).

For this reason, I now recommend that people use 'X' instead of '-'.  For historical reasons, synthesis tools interpret either of these as a don't care.  With the introduction of `?=`, if you assign an output to "----" and then compare it with `?=` to anything, the result is '1' (aka TRUE).

Hence, I recommend that you recode your when others as:

```
        when others => res <=(others => 'X');
```

Comment: I normally use `'U'` instead of `'X'` for returns that should not be used. It makes no difference during synthesis, but lets me treat `'X'` in the synthesis output as a warning rather than as an expected state.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it is because it doesn't make sense to assign a Don't Care. Don't Care is a umbrella grouping that represents multiple valid, but distinct, values so it only makes sense as a comparison condition, not as a write value because you can only write one value.

It's like positive or negative numbers. Each represents a group of different distinct values so while it makes sense in a comparison to determine whether a value is part of the group or not, it doesn't make sense to assign the group itself to a single value. For example, if I tried to assign "all positive numbers" to an integer, that doesn't make any sense.

Besides, if you ever need to write a Don't Care, you might as well just write any distinct value to it. But even that is pointless: Just don't modify the register it at all. Just use the `null` keyword to do nothing.